Android MediaPlayer SurfaceView video restarts on resume
Following is my code to play a video from an url
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    SurfaceView sv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        
        sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        SurfaceHolder holder = sv.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    mp.setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                    mp.setDataSource("https://v2.chartboost.com/videoads/636e2334a790a80850ecd48b_720-1668162356.mp4");
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mp!= null) {
             mp.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
        mp.setSurface(null);
    }
}

The above code does not give me the expected result. When the app moves to the background and is brought to the foreground, the video restarts instead of resuming. I have tried many things, but it is still not working.
Note: I can't use TextureView due to requirements.
Update:
I tried to seekTo method it works but screen appears black for a fraction of a second
mp.seekTo(currentPosition, SEEK_CLOSEST);


try this
create a an Application class then initialize the media player there
public class MyApplication extends Application {
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }
public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

in the manifest
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"

then in your class
   public class YourClass extends AppCompatActivity {
        private MediaPlayer mp;
//introduce a new variable  
 `int currentPosition = 0;`

//inside oncreate
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
        mp = app.getMediaPlayer();

oncreate player
 mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition); // Seek to saved position

// your other code
 @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
       mp.pause();
       currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition(); // Save the current position
       }
        mp.setSurface(null); // Release the surface
     }
   });

then update your on pause/onResume
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mp != null && currentPosition > 0) {
            mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
        currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition(); // Save the current position
    }
    mp.setSurface(null); // Release the surface
}


I have added update with seekTo I am getting black screen for a fraction of a second.

i hope the resume issue is fixed

Not yet fixed black screen is visible on resume for a fraction of a second

i have update the answer...check out the new changes

Still getting black screen for a fraction

use view model class

The issue with the video restarting instead of resuming when the app is brought back to the foreground is likely because mp.setSurface(null); is called in onPause(). This action releases the surface, and the MediaPlayer loses its connection to the video rendering surface, causing it to reset.
To fix this, you can manage the MediaPlayer state more carefully. Instead of setting the surface to null, you can simply pause the MediaPlayer in onPause() and properly handle the surface creation in surfaceCreated().
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    }
}


did you try the solution ?
